# Database object instantiate not found while instantiating

Tags: .net, postgresql

I have a connection to database (Postgressql) and in the server explorer i can see it and connect to it but i can not instantiate it in my controller

```
 public CentralEntities testDB = new CentralEntities();
```

the name is CentralEntities,and i get this error which says CentralEntities has not been found are you missing a reference ?strange thing is it used to work till yesterday

Comment: Where do you define the `CentralEntities` class?  Also, if it "used to work until yesterday" then that's a pretty narrow window of source control history for you to examine to find out what changed.  Worst case, roll back to before it broke and start re-implementing the changes since then.

Comment: @David thats the name the connection i made,its in the web.config,the name of my app is WebMax,could be its dll is missed in the references? very strange

Comment: Well, in the code you're showing, it's the name of a class.  And the error is telling you that the class isn't found.  Regardless of anything in your database or in your configuration, a class has to be defined in order to be used.

Comment: but in the server explorer,when you create a connection it has a name right?you can directly instantiate it in the code @David

Comment: Not without a defined class you can't.  Maybe there is some tooling in Visual Studio which creates a class for you in that functionality, that's certainly possible.  But a class needs to exist before you can use it.  The error is telling you that it can't find that class.  If you're using a tool to generate code then perhaps you need to invoke that tool again.

Comment: @David its works now,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the hints from david,turned out the class which is auto generated was missing,by adding it to the project using backup,the issue solved